# Display SWT token after authentication against IdP with ACS

Tags: odata, acs

I'm trying to create an OData service that will use authentication & authorization provided by ACS.

I was able to configure ACS but now I need to provide ability to users of the service to generate their SWT token to add it into "Authorization" header. I though to create a web page that will provide list of available IdPs and will display SWT token after successful authentication.

How to do it?

Comment: It sounds like you want to host a website that will act like an RP, redirecting the user to ACS and then to the identity provider and back, and then simply display the SWT received from ACS. If so that SCB's links should give you the code you need to do this, but I'd be interested to know more about your scenario. What is the nature of your OData client? Do you have a website making OData calls on the user's behalf for example?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to create JavaScript application that consumes existing OData (.NET) service. I would like to protect the OData service using ACS. Currently I'm struggling to retrieve SWT token that should be inserted into authorization header by the Javascript application while calling my service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCB's links are an excellent start here. It sounds like in addition to your OData service, you want to host a website that's capable of fetching and caching the SWT token issued by ACS so that it can be uses to make authenticated calls to your OData service on the user's behalf.

You can do this with a WIF based site like in the [ACS sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185938.aspx) but you need to provide your own custom security token handler so that it understands SWT tokens, which aren't natively supported by WIF.

Check out the [april 2011 identity training kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14347) which offers cues on how to do this. You can find SimpleWebToken and SimpleWebTokenHandler classes that build on the WIF library in the Windows Phone 7 sample for example. Check out step 38 of that walkthrough where it shows how to add the SimpleWebTokenHandler to your site's the web.config.

With all that working, you'll also want to configure saveBootstrapTokens="true" in the microsoft.identityModel/service section of your web.config as well. That way, your website can grab the SWT token like so:

```
SimpleWebToken swt = ((IClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).BootstrapToken as SimpleWebToken
```

Comment: I am doing something like this. I get the bootstrapped token and are able to get it transmitted to the client. It looks like this: http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2fws%2f2005%2f05%2fidentity%2fclaims%2fnameidentifier=HM81Sv2xnRD6P%2bm2W2T%2feBAfAhH2ZTMMxSBBOQ1Rxqs%3d&http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2faccesscontrolservice%2f2010%2f07%2fclaims%2fidentityprovider=uri%3aWindowsLiveID&Audience=http%3a%2f%2f77.75.160.102%3a48451%2f&ExpiresOn=1348788305&Issuer=https%3a%2f%2ftraffictheory.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&HMACSHA256=hLqNJd%2b1ZzgxqYY%2fXGQuOdmNpHBmWy0X7n1hO0mPVrY%3d    Problem is:

Comment: From the Client i dont know what to do with this token, should it be set directly into the authentication header?

Comment: Right now my website just hit a authentication failed event on the FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to show a page that lists the available providers.

Microsoft have a very good example of how to hook up ACS which includes showing the auto generated list of providers.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/

In regards to hooking OData to the ACS the Data Access team also have a very good walk through series on their blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/01/20/oauth-2-0-and-odata-protecting-an-odata-service-using-oauth-2-0.aspx